# Rails selecting all columns

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, rails-activerecord

I have an `Article` model class with a one-to-many connection to the `User` model

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :articles
end
```

When I run

```
article = Article.find(1)
article.user.username
```

The last statement loads the entire table. Selecting all columns is one of the performance's evil. This is the Rails console output:

```
User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

But I want just the `username` column.

Is there a way to do it using the same notation (`model_instance.model_instance.column`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the relationship between both models and get the needed User:

```
User.select(:name).joins(:articles).find_by(articles: { id: 1 }).username
# SELECT  "users"."username" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "articles" ON "articles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
```

It also can be written as with an slight change in the query:

```
User.select(:name).joins(:articles).find_by('articles.id = 1').username
# SELECT  "users"."username" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "articles" ON "articles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE (articles.id = 1) LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
```

Or in case using `where` you must access an specific record from the result:

```
User.select(:name).joins(:articles).where(articles: { id: 1 }).first.username
# SELECT  "users"."username" FROM "users" INNER JOIN "articles" ON "articles"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "articles"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?
```